# Is there any PERFORMANCE - difference between inner join and simple join?

Tags: sql, join

Is there any performance - difference between inner join and simple join? 
i.e. does either of them have a better execution plan and/or execution time?
And will both these approaches always yield same result sets?

Comment: Probably none, but you need to specify which database. Then soneone can tell you how to read the execution plans.

Comment: Oh, and some sample SQL to show the two queries you are looking at wouldn't hurt either. I suspect they are literally the same, like `x++` vs `x=x+1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JOIN` with no qualifier is just an abbreviation for `INNER JOIN`, they are exactly the same. If any database had a performance difference, I would report it as a bug.